# Bootstrap 4 buttons next and previous not showing

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm stuck to make a carousel in bootstrap 4.

It's working perfect but it doesn't shot the right button and left button only 3 colums bellow to switch to them but i don't know how to add those buttons that looks like this < >.

This is my button code

```
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#firstCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a> 

        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#firstCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-controls)..

Glyphicons (`icon-*`) are no longer included with Bootstrap 4.

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href=".." role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href=".." role="button" data-slide="next">
         <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

[Bootstrap 4 Carousel with controls](https://www.codeply.com/go/gfkebjEW9l)

Comment: Is there a dark version of the buttons ? because on a white background these are also invisible almost

Answer (score 0):

If you are using font awesome with you bootstrap you can replace like this :

```
<span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
With
<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>

<span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
With
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
```